# How do I "group" sets in Rails' jbuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I've got a set of "player" and "team" models in my RoR app (a JSON API) representing a sports team, with a "roster" model acting as the middleman in a many-to-many relationship. In the "roster" view, I'm trying to 'group' the players by team with jbuilder, but I can't figure out the proper code to do this.

My current jbuilder view code (index.json.jbuilder) looks like this:

```
json.rosters @rosters do |roster|
    json.team_id       roster.team.team_id
    json.team_name     roster.team.team_name
    json.player_id     roster.player.player_id
    json.first_name    roster.player.first_name
    json.last_name     roster.player.last_name
end
```

This outputs the following JSON:

```
{
    "rosters": [
        {
            "team_id": "1",
            "team_name": "Dallas Mavericks",
            "player_id": "1",
            "first_name": "Dirk",
            "last_name": "Nowitzki"
        },
        {
            "team_id": "1",
            "team_name": "Dallas Mavericks",
            "player_id": "2",
            "first_name": "Rajon",
            "last_name": "Rando"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question: **how can I get jbuilder to output the data in this format instead**? :

```
{
    "rosters": [
        {
            "team_id": "1",
            "team_name": "Dallas Mavericks",
            "players": [
                {
                    "player_id": "1",
                    "first_name": "Dirk",
                    "last_name": "Nowitzki"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "2",
                    "first_name": "Rajon",
                    "last_name": "Rando"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Some side notes:

- For those wondering why the team-player relation is many-to-many, it's because players are allowed to change teams. The roster table has start- and end-date fields that represent a player's tenure on the team, representing a changing roster over time; this isn't shown in the above example for lack-of-clutter's sake.
- I could probably do this more easily in the Team view, but I don't want to return roster information there since it's primarily used for listing teams. Might end up being be a lot of data to unconditionally pull if I include the roster stuff each time.
- I'm using Sequel as my ORM, not ActiveRecord, so if a solution involves twiddling the source data before sending it to jbuilder, i'm not sure if any AR magic will apply. Still rather new to all this.